# Comparing dates to the ":new" table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a beginner to SQL, so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a trigger in SQL. This code is giving me trouble:

```
select brw.borage, bt.agelower, bt.ageupper 
into borage, minage, maxage
from borrower brw
  inner join loan ln on ln.borid = brw.borid
  inner join bookcopy bc on ln.bcid = bc.bcid
  inner join booktitle bt on bt.isbn = bc.isbn
where ln.bcid = :new.bcid
and ln.borid = :new.borid;
-- and ln.dateout = :new.dateout;
```

The primary key in the loan table is composed of "bcID", "borID" and "dateOut".
When I comment out the last line, I get the newly added line(s) to the table.
With the last line uncommented though, it won't work!

I just get this error (with the line uncommented):

```
Row 34: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
```

meaning oracle did not find any rows that match the query criteria.

NOTE: When I uncomment the line, I also remove the semicolon above it.

Comment: What table is this trigger defined on?  Is `DATEOUT` being defined in a (possibly different) trigger?

Comment: @JustinCave The trigger is defined on the "Loan" table. DateOut is a date field in the loans table. The only trigger I have is the one I'm trying to create right now, and it has a create or replace at the top :) I am trying to avoid posting all of the code since it's part of an assignment, and I will risk getting plagiarized (for my own work) if I post more without carefully editing it.

Comment: @JustinCave DateOut is not being defined or declared anywhere, but it is part of the Loans table. Should I be declaring it or something?

Comment: Is this on an INSERT trigger, a DELETE trigger, or an UPDATE trigger? For the first two, could a default on the dateout column be causing the mismatch in data? I would make sure that the data in :new.dateout is what you expect it to be...

Comment: before or after trigger? With a before trigger, the values in `:new` have not yet been put into the table.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance it's a Before trigger. Can you put it in an answer? Putting it as an AFTER trigger seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.  First off, a row-level trigger on table `A` should not query table `A`.  In general, doing so is going to generate an "ORA-04091: table is mutating" error.  Since your trigger is defined on `LOAN`, the query should not reference the `LOAN` table.  It should only reference the data for the current row in the `:NEW` record.

That being the case, you probably want something like this (note that I'm guessing about the cardinality of the relationships between the tables here)

```
select brw.borage
  into borage
  from borrower brw
 where brw.borid = :new.borid;

select bt.agelower, bt.ageupper 
  into minage, maxage
  from bookcopy bc on :new.bcid = bc.bcid
       inner join booktitle bt on bt.isbn = bc.isbn;
```

You could combine the two queries but I don't see an easy way to do that without making the result more complex than you probably want.

Additionally, you really want to avoid having local variables that share the name of a column in your database (like `borage`).  That tends to generate rather puzzling scope resolution bugs.  For example, using the `SCOTT.EMP` table

There are no employees with an `EMPNO` of -17

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2    from emp
  3   where empno = -17;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

But when I write a simple PL/SQL block that tries to count the number of employees with an `EMPNO` of -17, the result I get is 14.  Can you spot the bug?

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    empno integer := -17;
  3    cnt   integer;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into cnt
  7      from emp e
  8     where e.empno = empno;
  9    dbms_output.put_line( cnt );
 10* end;
SQL> /
14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The problem is that when I wrote `e.empno = empno`, I clearly intended the left-hand side of the expression to reference the `EMPNO` column in the `EMP` table and the right-hand side of the expression to reference the local variable `EMPNO`.  Unfortunately for me, however, Oracle resolves the unqualified `EMPNO` first to a column in the table and only then to the local variable of the same name.  If you're using named PL/SQL blocks, you can work around that by using the name of the block as the alias for the local variable but virtually no one ever does that.

Instead, in order to avoid these sorts of problems, most developers will use some sort of distinctive prefix for variable names.  For example, I use `P_` as the prefix for parameter names, `L_` as the prefix for local variables, and `G_` as the prefix for package global variables.  That's a relatively common convention but other conventions exist.  The important thing is just to have some way of ensuring that you never have a local variable and a column name that use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ignore this error and continue execution of trigger, you can just add

```
exception
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  NULL
```

so the body of your trigger looks like

```
begin
   select brw.borage, bt.agelower, bt.ageupper 
   into borage, minage, maxage
   from borrower brw
   inner join loan ln on ln.borid = brw.borid
   inner join bookcopy bc on ln.bcid = bc.bcid
   inner join booktitle bt on bt.isbn = bc.isbn
   where ln.bcid = :new.bcid
   and ln.borid = :new.borid;
   and ln.dateout = :new.dateout;
   // other actions

   exception
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL
end;
```